# How to loop union in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to loop a union result. It mean I will union data by quarter(3 months). I used WITH, but I don't know clearly about it.(P/s: date is formated string: 'dd/MM/yyyy', not a datetime).

```
declare @quarter int;
declare @year int;
declare @i int;
set @quarter = 1;
set @year = 2011;
set @i = 1;

with temp(code, date, value) as 
(select code,date,value from test 
    where convert(int,substring(date,4,2))= @quarter*3+@i 
    and right(date,4)=@year 
    union all 
select code,date,value from test 
    where convert(int,substring(date,4,2))= @quarter*3+@i+1 
    and right(date,4)=@year and from temp where @i <= 3
)
select * from temp;
```

Example: in January have 1 record. February have 2 records, March have 3 records, April have 4 records. In above select, if I choose @quarter=1, it includes 3 months: January,February, March: 6 records(not include April).

Comment: Why is the format of your date relevant? Are you storing dates as strings? Why? Can you show the data that is actually in the table `test` and what are your desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're storing dates in an inappropriate manner, you're never going to have a working index on those columns, so the query will be slow for any reasonable amount of data.

But I don't see why you don't just use the built in functions that should give you the data:

```
SELECT code,date,value from test where
    DATEPART(year,CONVERT(datetime,date,103)) = @year and
    DATEPART(quarter,CONVERT(datetime,date,103)) = @quarter
```

---

Format `103` for the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) function exactly matches the format you're storing, so there's no need to do any messy string manipulation.

Comment: quarter not a datetime, it is quarter of year, example: one quarter includes: Jan,Feb,Mar. 2nd quarter is: March,May,Jun, 3rd quarter is: Jul,Aug,Sep and last quarter is: Oct,Nov, Dec.

Comment: @PhamMinh - [`DATEPART(quarter,<datevalue>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) will return a value between 1 and 4, giving the quarter of the year, which seems to match your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

```
declare @quarter int
declare @year int
set @quarter = 1
set @year = 2011

select  code
        ,date
        ,value 
from    test
where   datepart(year, cast(substring(date, 7, 4) + substring(date, 4, 2) + substring(date, 1, 2) as datetime)) = @year
    and datepart(q, cast(substring(date, 7, 4) + substring(date, 4, 2) + substring(date, 1, 2) as datetime)) = @quarter
```

EDIT:

Hmm...
Just noticed that you dont have a date, but a string of a date.

Expect an update here soon...

EDIT2:

Updated the dates of the where clause to be casted into a real datetime

Comment: Thanks, I followed Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: No problem, it seems to be the same solution, but his convert was far better than mine. :)